# Executing button action in secondary thread

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, ios5, nsthread

I want to know why I can't run the button action in secondary thread(see below the secondary thread code), when I do so the APP gets crashed and shows me the below error message.

```
NSThread *thread = [[NSThread alloc]initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(insertdata) object:nil];
[thread start];

void _WebThreadLockFromAnyThread(bool), 0x6a8cfe0: Obtaining the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. UIKit should not be called from a secondary thread.

bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0x6a8cfe0: Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...

1   WebThreadLock
2   -[UIFieldEditor setText:andSetCaretSelectionAfterText:]
3   -[UITextField setText:]
4   -[XYZ reset]
5   -[XYZ insertdata]
6   -[NSThread main]
7   __NSThread__main__
8   _pthread_start
9   thread_start
```

But when I change the thread to main thread(see below main thread code) I don't see any crash and my APP runs perfectly. Can anyone explain what is the difference, why I cannot run the action secondary thread.

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(insertdata) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error messages told you the exact reason:

> Obtaining the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the
>   web thread. UIKit should not be called from a secondary thread.

If the operation doesn’t take long, there’s no point in executing it on a background thread. If the operation *does* take long, you should separate the data retrieval (or whatever it is that takes long) from the UI update, run the data retrieval in background and then return back to the main thread to update the UI. Preferably using GCD:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_NORMAL, 0), ^{
    [self downloadData]; // takes long
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self updateUI]; // here you can safely call UIKit
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you for the clarification,So we have to use the secondary thread operation only when we are downloading or doing some background operations. So how does GCD(Grand Central Dispatch) is similar to secondary thread, how to switch from secondary to main thread in background operation.

Comment: You can use background threads for most things except UIKit. GCD is much better than explicit thread management, read the docs. The switch from background thread to the main thread is already illustrated by the code sample above, it’s the “dispatch on main queue” thing.

Comment: May I know how to update the UI. Suppose if my UI contains textField named resultsText ,what will updateUI contains ?

Comment: Probably just `[resultsText setText:@"some data"]`. This part is completely dependent on what exactly your code is supposed to do.

Comment: I just tried with resultsText.text=nil. but even after that it is causing web thread lock

Comment: Most probably you’re doing something slightly wrong and still call the code on a wrong thread. Take a look at `+[NSThread isMainThread]` to check if you’re on the main thread indeed. If you still have trouble, I suggest posting a new question with a code sample.